# Copy sheet in new workbok and save it with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote this code that goes through a data validation list and copy a worksheet in a new workbook. I want to save it but I can`t. The loop doesn`t give me an error and keeps copying and pasting in new workbooks but it actually never save a copy of the workbook in the directory I set up

```
Dim ValidationList As Range
Set ValidationList = Range("BF1:BF13")
VCount = ValidationList.Count


For i = 1 To VCount
FolderPath = "C:\Users\A734810\Desktop\Efficiency"
namesheet = Cells(i, 58)
Path = FolderPath & namesheet & "\*.xlsx"
Filename = Dir(Path)

Range("A8") = Cells(ValidationList(i).Row, ValidationList.Column)

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Professionals comparative").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=Filename

Next
```

Comment: Haven't seen the rest of the code but try this `ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=FolderPath & namesheet & "\" & Filename`

Comment: i think it should be `ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=FolderPath & "\" & namesheet & ".xlsx"` since Filename on current code returns folder path

Comment: @winghei: I thought of that but I assumed that the cell `Cells(i, 58)` will have "\" :)

Answer (score 5):

```
Path = FolderPath & namesheet & "\*.xlsx"
```

The above is correct provided the cell `Cells(i, 58)` has `\` And I guess you have a "\" becuase as per your post you are **not getting any errors**

The problem is here

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=Filename
```

The files are getting saved but not at the location that you think it will ;)

`Filename` just has the name of the file. You need to change it to

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=FolderPath & namesheet & "\" & Filename
```

Comment: Glad to have helped :)